# No such module PushNotifications (Swift 4 + Xcode 9.0) Firebase

Tags: firebase, push-notification

Use Xcode9, Swift4 no work on real Iphone6

Two issues:

1. Redefinition of Module 'Firebase'
2. No such module 'UserNotifications'

but if I use Simulator all is good!

Comment: Is there a question here? Can you include some code so we can see where the error occurs? Can you update and clarify the question so we understand what you are asking? Also, please see [How to Create a MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Project with Notification. I Use Firebase Pods. when I use Simulator No errors, but if I try to build app in real device I see two issues.

Comment: Can you include the actual error text and perhaps showing the code (as text please) as to where it's stopping?

Answer (score 0):

install firebase pod and import following modules

```
import Firebase
import FirebaseMessaging
import UserNotifications
```